# Adding jQuery to a webform

Tags: 8, javascript, webforms

Trying to count selected radios in a webform, I managed to make it work outside drupal (please see link below) but I'm not sure how to add it to my theme/webform.

https://jsfiddle.net/j9q75Lay/

I created a .js file with the jQuery code in it as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var a =  $("input[value='a']:checked").length
        var b =  $("input[value='b']:checked").length
        var c =  $("input[value='c']:checked").length
        $('.a_results').text(a)
        $('.b_results').text(b)
        $('.c_results').text(c)        
    })
});
```

I saved the .js file in my theme's /js folder and I added it to mytheme.libraries.yml file like this :

```
    global-scripts:
  js: 
    js/jscripts.js: {}
    js/webform_count_radios.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

I drush cr

I created a textfield element in my webform and added the "a_results" class to it. (I shall add two more each for the b_results, and c_results)

I later added an Advanced HTML/text type webform element with the following to display all results from the 3 categories :

```
<p><span class="a_results">0</span> A's &ndash; <span class="b_results">0</span> B's&ndash; <span class="c_results">0</span> C's</p>
```

But none is working yet! Actually having the .js file seems to break other js dependent features in my theme/webform (e.g. iCheck and rrssb block).

This is my first such trial and am not sure where I'm going wrong.

Thank you for your kind help.

EDIT:

I re-defined the webform library in mytheme.libraries.yml as follows :

```
webform:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      webform/webform.css: {}
  js: 
    webform/webform_count_radios.js: { preprocess: false }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Adding the **{ preprocess: false }** property made other scripts work properly. But still the count js is not working!

I added to the webform-submission-form.html.twig :

```
{{ attach_library('mytheme/webform') }}
```

Still no luck!  What am I missing ?!!!

EDIT:
After changing the script as per below, it's attaching now (I get the popup alert) but still the count function not working!

```
(function($) {
alert('Test');
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var a =  $("input[value='a']:checked").length
        var b =  $("input[value='b']:checked").length
        var c =  $("input[value='c']:checked").length
        $('.a_results').text(a)
        $('.b_results').text(b)
        $('.c_results').text(c)        
    });
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT: Actually the above change seems to fix it but (while on the webform test page) the count only works when I re-select any of the selected radios and then the results are updated in the span element NOT the text-field elements.

However, the results are empty on the preview page (why ? still on mytheme!) and results pages (since that's on the admin theme)! How can I make them appear on there too ?

Comment: does it attach properly aka test with alert('test'); does that work ?

Comment: @Taggart Jensen, thanks for your reply. No it doesn't seem to be attaching! I also tried adding the code as "Custom Javascript" in my webform settings but still no luck.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it tweaking the script but still have to make the results show on the preview and results pages. Please see my edited post.

Comment: global-styling: Attached libs to all pages of your theme only, if you want better control over this better to do it in a custom module not the theme look up attach js in a module and look up hook_form_alter also its onchange, you probably want an on load as well

Comment: I ended up making it work on the textfield input and thus the results are now saved and showing up on both the preview page and the webform results page. @TaggartJensen, I'll try to follow your kind advice but I need to start studying how to create custom modules since I have no experience there at all yet.